# What is the best low power wireless transmitter?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I would like to send a sensor signal (e.g. Temperature) wirelessly to a computer for a short distance (e.g.3~5 meters). The challenge is I have a very low power source (3V 50mV).
I am thinking of using a

1. Bluetooth chip: (Good quality signal, but I feel that the chips that I found online are power-draining)
2. Antenna: with the amount of power I am delivering noise might be an issue if I am it is impossible to operate of high frequencies.

What is the best way to transmit my signal from the sensor wirelessly with as low power as possible?

Comment: "*3V 50mV*". Do you mean "3 V, 50 mA"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference for sensor applications like temperature and humidity that don't need fast updates is a MICRF112/MICRF211 pair. The MICRF112 draws < 1 uA in standby and pairs nicely with just about any low power microcontroller you like. In the right setup you can get months of use from a couple AAA batteries.

Comment: I am thinking of using a thermistor for heat sensing. Do you have a better recommendation?

Comment: TMP36 or the DS18B20 are my typical go-tos but every once in a while I'll go with a DHT11 to have a humidity reading as well as temp. MCP9700 isn't so bad either.